# How to set content-type when using initWithContentsOfUrl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, content-type

Basically I want to set

Content-Type: application/json;

in order to call a dot net web service and have it return json to an iphone application.

At the moment I have

```
NSString * jsonres = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

What do I need instead in order to issue a blocking request ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use  NSURLMutableRequest, here you can add headers for content-type and the sort, here is a r eference, http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableURLRequest, once you set  up your request you can add the value using this method - (void)addValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field something like

```
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: Yep, I think that will do it.  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: although its not a blocking style request, instead using delgates and callbacks - which will involve some re-architecting!

Comment: for blokcing style you just gotta do an sync call (forgot to mention this sorry) you can use NSURLConnections method called + (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error, heres a link http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:

Comment: Thanks. Just figured that out myself and came back here to change my comments :-) You got there 5 hours ago!

Comment: Please don't use sendSynchronousRequest from the main thread. It results in apps that perform poorly.

Comment: I think the syntax may have changed from addValue to setValue, but I'm not an expert on Objective C. Someone who knows more than me should verify that the API changed. `[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"]`. This works for me, but perhaps there's something I'm missing; hence, I didn't edit your post. Also, forHTTPHeaderField may be misspelled.  I suspect there are some syntax issues here even though this information is *very* helpful! :)

Comment: Then again sendSynchronousRequest has been deprecated for a while now. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198404/nsurlsession-with-nsblockoperation-and-queues for the NSURLSession equivalent.